# How to delete an extension from Magento Developer Profile 'My Extensions'?

Tags: extensions, magento-connect, marketplace

I want to submit an extension I developed to the Magento Connect Marketplace for review.
However, I uploaded a wrong Icon and I'm not able to delete it again. I uploaded the correct picture in the screenshots section and defined it as the Base Image but I can't delete the old one.
Neither can I delete the whole extension btw.
Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reaching out to them at connect@magento.com, but in my experience they won't delete any listings, period. There's no way to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

So far as I know, Connect was largely deprecated and unmanaged: a Wild West of non-curated extensions. It has been discontinued.

Extensions have now been migrated to the more curated Marketplace, and it's likely people will find this question when looking for ways to delete extensions from the Marketplace.

Extension deletion is complex (delete just the latest or oldest version, or the entire extension's history and all files stored for it on the repository? What should happen to marketing content, reviews and ratings?). Deletions can be requested by contacting marketplace@magento.com with details of what you're trying to achieve.

Another way I've seen deletions requested, for extensions which have never reached the store, is to rename the extension to "delete me". Such an extension would not pass through the manual or marketing review process, and the reviewers would delete it.

The email method is likely faster, however: possibly LOTS faster.